# Explain what happened in following code in c#

Tags: c#, oop

Is this creates 1000 person objects?

```
public class Person
{
   public string FirstName;  
   public string LastName;    
}

Person person;    
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    person = new Person();
}
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? Have you ever read anything about class, object and for loop subjects? Sorry but your question is really about some basic fundamentals of C# language. You can easily find _how your code works_ reading the basic rules of language and object orianted.

Answer (score 3):

The code creates 1000 person objects, but keeps a reference to only the last-created one. All the others will exist in memory for a while, but are unreferenced and unusable and therefore will at some point be reclaimed by the garbage collector.

(To be precise, the code as given doesn't actually tell us how long the last reference will be alive. If `person` is not referenced at any point other than the code given, it will also become eligible for collection after the loop and could be collected at any time thereafter.)

Answer (score 2):

- Yes , it creates 1000 objects as you call constructor 1000 times
- As they're all assigned to the same variable only the last instance will be referenced after the loop, rest will be collected by GC at some point in time

Comment: And why did someone downvote this answer too, which (like my downvoted answer) is also correct. I think we have a curious fellow in our midst.

Comment: _"only the last instance will be alive"_ - not entirely correct. The rest will still be _alive_ just _orphaned_ until GC'd which could well happen during the loop

Comment: @MickyDuncan updated. Though i still think that distinguishing between `alive` / `referenced` / `orhpaned` for this question makes little sense

Comment: Reads better now but.  I'm not the downvoter, in fact here's a +1.  `alive` is important if one is going to quote `GC`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new Person object 1000 times. In every loop cycle you assigning new object to person variable. Variable can keep only one object, so all previously created will be lost (by garbage collector)

If you want to create 1000 person object and assign them to other variables you should use collections in C#. For example:

```
Person[] persons = new Person[1000];

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    persons[i] = new Person();
}
```

Comment: Yes the code above creates 1000 Person objects. It assigns all 1000 to the same variable so only the last created is accessible.

Comment: Dovnvoter please explain your vote. My answer is totally correct.

Comment: Your answer is not correct. The code in the question does create 1000 person objects. Also I'm not the down voter.

Comment: "assigning 1000 times **new** Person object ". What you dont understand? Here are 2 simple keywords: **1000 times**, and a **new Person object**

Comment: Your answer to his question say no but your explanation says yes.

Comment: Consider re-wording _"This code assigning 1000 times a new Person object to person variable"_. I'm not entirely sure the grammar is correct

Comment: ok corrected. Next time, I will more attract the attention to the correctness of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This code instantiate a `Person` to a heap 1000 times. And as a result 999 will be garbage, but last one assigned to `person` variable